# Is there a phrase to express a thing has already happened really soon after something has been happened?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

My child has been sick for just 2 days and now he is much thinner than he was 2 days ago.

Do you have a common phrase to express that idea in English?

U am not sure "**no sooner.. than**" is suitable in this case?

For example, No sooner have you been sick for just 2 days, you are much thinner than you were 2  days ago.

**Is there a common phrase to express a thing has already happened really soon after something has been happened?**

Comment: *Suddenly*, is often used to express this.

Comment: "My child has been sick for just two days and he is **already** much thinner than he was" (you don't really need to specify "two days ago", because that's obvious).

Comment: Please edit to make the question clearer, because I took a different meaning away than others have. Your example is "X happened, so Y is a result." Is your point that Y happened very soon after X? Or that X itself is very recent? If it's the latter, then words like "just" are enough: "You have **just** been sick." or similar expressions like "recently," "lately," etc.

Answer (score 1):

A common phrase used to mean immediately after is “**right after**”:

Right after being sick for 2 days, you are much thinner than you were 2 days ago.

You could also just write “immediately after,” but depending on context, this sounds slightly more forceful.

Answer (score 0):

***As a result***

> **As a result of something**
> phrase
>
> because of something:
>
> - Profits have declined as a result of the recent drop in sales.
> - As a
>   result of the accident, he suffered permanent brain damage.
> - In
>   future, extreme weather events are likely to be worse and more
>   frequent as a result of climate change.
> - She died last week as a
>   result of complications from Parkinson's disease.
> - It was suspected
>   that the building had collapsed as a result of structural failure.

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-a-result-of)

So:

> As a result of the illness you got very thin

I would say no sooner than would be used like

> No sooner than you get over 1 cold, you get another one.

So it is about things pilling on top of each other not because of each other.